# Form Submit to change/modify session variables in PHP

Tags: php, forms, session, submit

At the top I have a session start and the session ID can be passed across all the webpages because the ID is the same on all, this also includes a session variable called 'username' with the value of Guest.
I want to change this variable to the one entered in the form.
This is my first post so sorry for any mistakes.

```
<form class="form1" method="post" action="./" id="form1">
<fieldset>
    <ul>
            <p>Please enter your username to continue to the webshop.</p>
            <label for="name">User Name:</label><span><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true"/></span>

            <input  class="submit .transparentButton" value="Next" type="submit" name="Submit"/> 

    </ul>
    <br/>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<?
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
     $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to server code or are trying to exploit some csrf bug??? The first case it's easy, on second what you are trying make no sense.

Comment: I know it's off topic. But ul element should have li element as its child element.

Comment: I am just trying to create a simple "log in" system where the user logs in with only a username which isn't stored anywhere outside the session.

Comment: @user2993761 I updated my answer, see if it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to take out `./` is in the `action=""` quotes like below (this is because you are using the same file to process the form)... and always start your php opening with `<?php`

```
<form class="form1" method="post" action="" id="form1">
<fieldset>
    <ul>
            <p>Please enter your username to continue to the webshop.</p>
            <label for="name">User Name:</label><span><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true"/></span>

            <input  class="submit .transparentButton" value="Next" type="submit" name="Submit"/> 

    </ul>
    <br/>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
     $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}
?>
```

And if you want to test it try something like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

    // Use the following code to print out the variables.
    echo 'Session: '.$_SESSION['username'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'POST: '.$_POST['username'];
}
?>
```

Tested the code after making the changes, and it works fine... look:

> [image: Tested screenshot]

---

**Update answer based of requests in the comments**

```
<form class="form1" method="post" action="./" id="form1">
    <fieldset>
       <ul>
            <p>Please enter your username to continue to the webshop.</p>
            <label for="name">User Name:</label><span><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true"/></span>

            <input  class="submit .transparentButton" value="Next" type="submit" name="Submit"/> 

       </ul>
       <br/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

PUT THIS IN YOUR index.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

        // Use the following code to print out the variables.
        echo 'Session: '.$_SESSION['username'];
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'POST: '.$_POST['username'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Looking at my code, and seeing as I am relatively new to PHP. I can't see where to put this. I am using the 'method = post' and that's all i know really, sorry.

Comment: This worked perfectly, Thanks all. I have fixed the ul-li problem as well. One last thing, because I can't use the action="./" anymore. Is there another way I can have the log in button also redirect me to the home (index.php) page without an extra button/link? Thanks  Also I would up-Vote but I am not able because this is a new account

Comment: @user2993761 If this answer worked for you, you can accept the answer with the check mark: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers ... As for redirect, I don't understand what you are asking, but you can redirect with `header('Location: index.php');`... but you must not print any html out before using this.

Comment: Basically My index.php is a home page, the log in page is accessed from there. Once I have logged in I want to be automatically redirected back to the index.php(homepage). Thanks

Comment: @user2993761 Then you need to put the second part of the code in the index page (homepage), and put the `action="./"` back... I'll update my answer showing you how.

Comment: Works great, exactly what I wanted. I didn't know php could be handled that way.